# "UnicodeDecodeError" while installing SciPy with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, pip, command-prompt

I'm trying to installing **SciPy** on Windows.

The problem is that my username for windows contains a "ò" and when I run `pip install Scipy` into the prompt i get **`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 50: invalid continuation byte`** and then several lines of errors.

Do you know how Can I solve this? I'm getting crazy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgrading pip error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte ???? in position #####: invalid continuation byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510743/upgrading-pip-error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-in)

Comment: Can you post the full error that you're getting (e.g. all of the lines of the traceback)