# pip install pillow 'utf-8' codec can't decode

Tags: python, utf-8, pip, installation, python-imaging-library

I use pip and pip3 and easy_install install pillow i got an error:

```
$ Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 55: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-        packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\梁生珺\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 55: invalid start byte
```

I am already used easy_install to update pip and pip3.

And I use pip install xxx.whl and pip install pillow.

But it useless. I don't know how to solve this problem. thanks much.

Comment: What's the full traceback?

Comment: This should solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906206/pip-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: @tiagoperes Probably best to flag as a duplicate rather than just a comment

Comment: I was reading this. so i am updating pip, but useless. i don't know how to use the second way...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906206/pip-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Comment: Which version of pip are you using? `pip -V`

Comment: @HåkenLid My pip version is 9.0.1

Comment: The error is possibly caused by your username directory, containing unicode characters.

There might be fix for it here:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4486

To install latests version from github, run `pip install https://github.com/pypa/pip`

Comment: @HåkenLid OK, I'ii try it.thanks much.

Comment: Under Windows, In my case, [changing the cmd.exe terminal to UTF-8 did the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line/388500#388500) Bests.-

Answer (score 1):

There have been several similar problems with `pip` on multiple versions. Sadly there is no proper fix, most of them are just temporary hacks.

You can attempt to install Pillow manually, by [downloading the source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) and running `python setup.py`.

You can also check out [this github thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251) which suggests replacing `return s.decode('utf-8')` in line 75 to `return s.decode('cp936')` which is the character encoding for simplified Chinese.

**Further Reading**

[upgrading pip error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510743/upgrading-pip-error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-in)

[pip UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906206/pip-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte)